# -ms-touch-action:none and child element vertical scrolling Windows Phone Css

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

For a windows phone 8 Html 5 App, I'm trying to fix the background location only to the view port, but allow child elements to scroll vertically. I've used the following, which thanks to -ms-touch-action:none; prevents the background from panning beyond the view port; however, when I had -ms-touch-action:manipulation to the child element it is never able to scroll.

```
html{
-ms-touch-action:none;
background- image : anyurl
background-size:100% 100%;

}

body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#scrolling-child{
-ms-touch-action:manipulation;
overflow:auto;
height : 10000 pixels;
width: 10000 pixels ;
}

<html>
 <body>
  <div id="scrolling-child">

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```